# Create a new branch on github + git fetch + git push fails

Tags: git, github

We had a problem with git a few days ago. A mate (aka A) created a new branch on github. Another mate (aka B) made the git fetch. On the git push git quitted for B: "Push rejected: push to origin/xxxxx was rejected".

As far as I know github doesn't commit nothing on branch creations, so why did the push fail? Would it have worked if he would have done a git pull between the fetch and the push? I tried to reproduce myself the error, but the workflow that failed for mate B worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `git fetch` is not equal to `git pull`. A `git fetch` will only fetch the reference information for different branches in the remote. You need to run `git pull` first. A git pull will run a `git fetch` and then a `git merge` of your local and remote branches. You can then push the changes.

Comment: @ChrisMaes, I prefer that too, but explaining rebase to someone not familiar with git is way too difficult

Comment: That's what I understood about it, but event that... Why did it worked for me? I didn't pull the changes too, but it worked. That's what I'm worried about. Maybe an option on my .gitconfig files?

Comment: no, nothing in .gitconfig can change that. Maybe you ran git pull or maybe it has something to do with your workflow. I don't have enough info to comment on that

Comment: If I do a git checkout instead of git pull t would be the same right? Thanks for answering!

Comment: If you did a `git checkout -t ` yes, you wouldn't have had to run `git pull`